$\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L} \rightarrow \text{AC}+\text{GCH}$.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction To Independence Proofs", thm 4.6 in VI, we are given the following:

Theorem. If $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$, then for all infinite ordinals $\alpha$, $\mathscr{P}(L(\alpha)) \subset L(\alpha^+)$.

The proof goes like this:

Let $\chi$ be a finite conjuction of axioms of $\sf{ZF}+\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ such that $$\forall M(M \ \text{transitive} \land \chi^M \rightarrow M = L(o(M))).$$ This is possible by theorem 3.9.


Assume $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$, and fix $A \in \mathscr{P}(L(\alpha))$. Let $X = L(\alpha) \cup \{A\}$. Then $|X| = |\alpha|$ by lemma 1.14 (1.14 uses  AC, but we have just seen that $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L} \rightarrow \text{AC}$). By a Löwenheim-Skolem argument followed by the Mostowski Collapsing Theorem there is a transitive $M$ such that $|M| = |\alpha|$, $X \subset M$ and $\chi^M \leftrightarrow \chi^{\mathbf{V}}$ (we have applied IV 7.10 with $\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{V}$). But $\chi^{\mathbf{V}}$ is true by $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$, so $\chi^{M}$ holds, whence $M = L(o(M))$. Since $|M| = |\alpha|$, $|o(M)| < \alpha^+$. Thus $A \in L(o(M)) \subset L(\alpha^+)$.

I think I understand the structure of the argument, but there is one step I don't understand:
"But $\chi^{\mathbf{V}}$ is true by $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$". Why is $\chi^{\mathbf{V}}$ true just because $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$?
Some other reflections:
The Löwenheim-Skolem (or perhaps Downwards Löwenheim-Skolem; let's abbreviate this as DLS) $\qquad (*)$ gives us

$$\forall B \ \forall X  \ \exists A[X \subset A \subset B \land A \prec B \land |A| \leq \max(|X|,|\mathcal{L}|)] \qquad \qquad (1)$$ where in our case, $|\mathcal{L}| = \omega$ since the language is countable/finitary (if that is the correct usage of finitary).

Now, we note that $A \subset L(\alpha)$. Since $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ and $A \in \mathbf{V}$, it follows that $A \in \mathbf{L}$, so it follows that $A \in L(\beta)$ for some $\beta$, presumably $\beta > \alpha$ (if no such $\beta$ existed, then we would already be done, I claim). Then by reflection, we can find some $\zeta > \beta$ so $\chi^{L(\zeta)}$ holds.
By DLS applied to $X,(L(\zeta),\in)$ (taking $B = L(\zeta)$ and $X = X$ in $(1)$)  where we use that $A \in L(\beta) \subset L(\zeta)$ so that $X = L(\alpha) \cup \{A\} \subset L(\zeta)$ we can find $\mu$ such that $X \subset \mu \subset L(\zeta)$, $\mu \prec L(\zeta)$ and $|\mu| \leq \max(\omega,|X|) = \max(\omega,|\alpha|)$. Now, I suppose $\mu$ inherits the order $\in$ from $L(\beta)$, so that we can talk about $(\mu,\in)$. But we still don't know whether $\mu$ is transitive.
If we now apply the Mostowski Collapse to $\mu$, we find that there is some $(N,\in)$ so that $(\mu,\in) \cong (N,\in)$, and furthermore $N$ is transitive.
Now, since $\mu \prec L(\beta)$, we have (by lemma 1.10 in Kunen, V) that for every formula $\phi(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})$, $\phi^{\mu}(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}) \leftrightarrow \phi^{L(\beta)}$. But by our earlier use of reflection, this means that $\chi^{\mu}$ holds, and by extension, it follows that $\chi^N$ holds. It follows from this ($N$ being transitive and $\chi^N$ holding) together with thm 3.9 (VI) that $N = L(o(N))$, where $o(N) = N \cap \mathbf{ON}$. Now, we know that $X \subset \mu$ and that we had an isomorphism $f:\mu \overset{\simeq}{\to} N$ for the $\in$-relation to $N$. My teacher claimed that it will follow that $f$ will act as the identity on $X$, so that $X \subset N$ (if someone has a more elaborate argument for this part I'd be happy) $\qquad$ (**).
Furthermore, we of course have \begin{align*} |\mu| &= |N|\\
&= |\alpha|.\end{align*}
Then we see that since $L(\alpha) \subset N$, $\alpha \leq o(N)$, and from $|N| = \alpha$, we see that $|o(N)| \leq |N| = |\alpha|$, so that $o(N) < \alpha^+$, since if $o(N) \geq \alpha^+$ then
\begin{align*}
|o(N)| &\geq |\alpha^+|\\
 &= \alpha^+ \qquad \qquad (\text{since $\alpha^+$ is a cardinal})\\
&> \alpha\\
& \geq |\alpha|,
\end{align*}
contradicting $|o(N)| \leq |\alpha|$.
Then $A \in L(o(M)) \subset L(\alpha^+)$ (which follows from $o(N) < \alpha^+$).
We have shown that $\mathscr{P}(L(\alpha)) \subset L(\alpha^+)$.
(*) I should comment and say that perhaps I should have called the Downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem the Downward Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem.
(**) What I would most like to know a more detailed argument about, is the step where we say that $f$ acts like the identity on $L(\alpha) \cup \{A\}$.
(***) Please point out if there are any general errors in the proof.

$\chi$ is a finite conjunction of axioms of ZF + V=L.

Hm, not sure I follow. I mean, in the more elaborate part I wrote down, it followed from the fact that we first by DLS found an elementary submodel (I believe it is so called), and then by mostowski collapse (again, I believe so called) found an isomorphism to some set $N$ with $\in$-relation respected by said isomorphism.

I’m just answering your first question why $\chi$ holds in $V$. $V$ satisfies ZF+V=L. $\chi$ is a conjunction of axioms of ZF+V=L. That’s all there is to it.

For the question about why the Mostowski collapse is the identity on $L(\alpha)\cup{A},$ note this set is transitive. (cf Kunen's reference to IV 7.10).

I got what you were answering, but I don't understand why $\mathbf{V}$ satisfies $\sf{ZF}+\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$. One can show from $\sf{ZF}^{-}$ that $\mathbf{V}$ is a model of $\sf{ZF}$ so since we are working in $\sf{ZF}$ (Kunen $\S4$, IV, first sentence), it follows that $\mathbf{V} \models \varphi$ for all sentences $\varphi$ in $\sf{ZF}$. Oh, okay, so if we assume $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ then $\mathbf{V} \models \sf{ZF}+ \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$. Do you agree? Or well, actually that all axioms of $\sf{ZF}$ are true in $\mathbf{WF}$, hm, what is needed for $\mathbf{WF} = \mathbf{V}$.

Hm, no perphaps this presents a problem, since then $\sf{ZF}^{-}$ would provide a model of $\sf{ZF}$, but would not this imply that we can show that $\sf{ZF}$ is consistent from a weaker theory ($\sf{ZF}^{-}$)? So I must have made atleast one error somewhere.

Yes, "we are working in ZF" means the same thing as "V satisfies ZF".  (Everything else is overcomplicating things, but to address your concern, remember that in ZF-, WF is merely a proper class model of ZF, not a set model, so we just get Con(ZF-)-> Con(ZF), not that ZF- proves Con(ZF).)

Ok, one can show in $\sf{ZF}^{-}$ that if foundation holds then $\mathbf{WF} = \mathbf{V}$, so indeed all axioms of $\sf{ZF}$ are true in $\mathbf{V}$ if we are working from $\sf{ZF} \supset \sf{ZF}^{-}$.
Regarding the last thing you wrote: That seems like an important distinction. Hmm, so in the first case we are saying that if $\sf{ZF}^{-}$ is consistent then $\sf{ZF}$ is consistent. The second case would rather be $\sf{ZF}^{-} \vdash \text{Con}(\sf{ZF})$.

This second case would indeed be a contradiction, since it would follow that $\sf{ZF}^{-} \vdash \text{Con}(\sf{ZF}) \rightarrow \text{Con}(\sf{ZF}^{-})$ so by transitivity of $\vdash$ $\sf{ZF}^{-} \vdash \text{Con}(\sf{ZF}^{-})$, contradicting Gödels $2^{\text{nd}}$-incompleteness.
Unless I am mistaken; it seem like this should follow from that fact that all sentences $\phi$ of $\sf{ZF}^{-}$ are true in $\sf{ZF}$ so if $\sf{ZF}$ is consistent then $\sf{ZF}^{-}$ must be consistent, otherwise we could derive $\bot$ in $\sf{ZF}^{-}$, but then also in $\sf{ZF}$.

Or actually, hmm, really $\sf{ZF}^{-} \not \vdash \text{Con}(\ulcorner \sf{ZF}^{-} \urcorner)$ is $2^{\text{nd}}$ gödel incompleteness, not what I wrote.

Not sure I follow all that but yes, $\sf ZF^-\vdash Con(ZF)$ would be violate the incompleteness theorem. And yes $\bf V=WF$ is equivalent to foundation over $\sf ZF^-,$ but bringing $\bf WF$ into things is missing the point... the point is that we're working in $\sf ZF$, so we're assuming $\bf V$ satisfies $\sf ZF.$ That's what it means to be working in $\sf ZF.$

(Or, if we're being very formal, the formulas $\phi$ and $\phi^{\bf V}$ are always logically equivalent as $\bf V$ is just the class defined by $x=x$... so since we're assuming each $\phi\in \sf ZF,$ we have $\phi^{\bf V}$ for each $\phi\in \sf ZF.$)

Thanks for keeping my sanity in check! :)
